# Python - PermissionError: [WinError 32] File being used by another process

Tags: python, pypdf

I have created a function that takes all my downloaded PDFs and merges them together and then deletes the old PDFs. When i run the code on my mac everything works fine, but when i run it on my work windows PC i get the following error. The error happens when i try to delete the old files with os.delete(file)

PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: "C:\Users\X\Downloads\file.pdf"

```
def pdf_merge(container):
    merger = PdfFileMerger(strict=False)
    allpdfs = [a for a in glob("C:\Users\X\Downloads\*.pdf")]
    sortedallpdfs = sorted(allpdfs, key=os.path.getmtime)
    [merger.append(pdf) for pdf in sortedallpdfs]
    with open(f"C:\Users\X\Desktop\MergedDocs\{container}", "wb") as new_file:
        merger.write(new_file)

    for file in allpdfs:
        os.remove(file)
```

I have tried restarting my computer and not open anything before running the program. I also thought that maybe it was OneDrive that was causing the problem, but pausing OneDrive syncing didn't help either.

Comment: Seems to be the exact same problem! I can delete the files myself not using python but not when the script is running just like in the one you linked.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution! This is the code to kill all the pendant file:

```
pathToClear = "{PATH GOES HERE}"

print(f"...Searching for active processes matching path: '{pathToClear}'")
for proc in psutil.process_iter(['name', 'open_files']):
    for file in proc.info['open_files'] or []:
        if pathToClear in file.path:
            print(f"Found process potentiall process potentially locking path. Killing: '{proc.info['name']}'")
            print("%-5s %-10s %s" % (proc.pid, proc.info['name'][:10], file.path))
            proc.kill()

print("Completed!")
```

I hope it can be useful for someone!